# Add dpi to seaborn or export them with a given dpi

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, dpi

I have a visualization code like:

```
for cluster in ready_couples_2.cluster.unique():
    sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
    # mask the cluster of interest
    is_cluster = ready_couples_2.cluster.eq(cluster)

    ax = ready_couples_2[~is_cluster].plot.scatter(x='longitude',y='latitude', c='gray') 

    ax = sns.scatterplot(data=ready_couples_2[is_cluster],
                    x='longitude', 
                    y='latitude',
                    hue='id_easy',
                    ax=ax)
    ax.legend_.remove()

    figure = ax.get_figure()    
    figure.savefig('test.png', dpi=500)

    plt.show()
```

But `figure` is saving only one plot out of given plots. How to save them all OR how to define DPI while plotting?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does save all of your figures, but because you don't change the file name the last plot will be the only one you see.

You can for example do

```
for ind, cluster in enumerate(ready_couples_2.cluster.unique()):
    ...
    figure.savefig('test%d.png' % ind, dpi=500)
```